# Sort by dictionary hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

My table model looks like this

model NiceFile

```
name:string
file_type:integer
```

then I have a dictionary like

```
{1=>'aaa', 2=>'bbb', 3=>'ccc'}
```

How can I sort records ordered by this dictionary?

Comment: Are keys in your Hash meant to be `file_type` values? And do you want to do your sorting inside the database or outside the database?

Comment: Yes,Keys are file_types. I like simple solutions.

Comment: Things aren't ordered by a dictionary--do you want things ordered by key, or value?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to sort in Ruby, then you could do something like this:

```
ordering = {1=>'aaa', 2=>'bbb', 3=>'ccc'}
files    = NiceFile.where(...).sort_by { |n| ordering[n.file_type] }
```

The `where(...)` is, of course, just a placeholder for whatever AR things you need to do to get your NiceFiles. This will work fine as long as none of your database operations care about the ordering; in practice this means that it'll usually be fine unless you're planning on using `limit` and `offset` to grab just a slice of the database results.

If you need to use your custom ordering inside the database, then you'd want to put your Hash into a table (say `ordering_table`), join to it, and order on the values. Something like this:

```
files = NiceFile.where(...).
                 joins('left join ordering_table on nice_file.file_type = ordering_table.file_type').
                 order('coalesce(nice_file.order_pos, 1000)').
                 limit(11)
```

The `coalesce` and `left join` are there in case you have `nice_file.file_type` values that aren't in your `ordering_table`.